# Can SELECT query have multiple WHERE IN functions?

Tags: php, mysql

Very noobish question perhaps but here it goes.

I have two arrays. One contains words and other numbers. After I implode them they print out like this:

$offers: word1, word2, word3...

and

$city: 1, 2, 3, 4...

I try to make a query from table 'offers' where $offers is matched against column 'offer' and $city against 'city_id'.

My query is:

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE offer IN ($offers) AND city_id IN ($city)";

    $result = mysql_query($query);                  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

            {


            $rows[] = $row['id'];


            }
```

This gives me only error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource... even it should bring me rows I have in my database table.

Thanks.

Ok. Found a solution. As my 1st array contains words I put quotes around each word:

```
function add_quotes($str) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}

$offers =  implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $offer_array));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select) (can't mark as such). If `$offers` and `$city` are arrays, you might want to [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/implode) first

Comment: yes, I have imploded them first like this: $city = implode(", ", $city_array);

Comment: Ok, and what is the sql error? Another problem could be that you need to wrap `$offers` because `.. IN (foo, bar)` is invalid and should be `.. IN ('foo', 'bar')`

Comment: Your $offer variable looks like `$offers: word1, word2, word3` which won't be accepted in `IN` clause because it expects `'word1', 'word2', 'word3'`. So ultimately your query fails, returning false. Which you are pssing to mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: Here's a useful bit of code: echo $query;